# Storing settings/data on microcontrollers non-volatile memory (STM32F103)

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, non-volatile-memory

I want to be able to store values in a non-volatile memory so that the microcontroller can load these settings at start up. These settings might change at run-time and it is important for the systems functionality that these settings are stored.

As far as I know the only non-volatile memory on the STM32F103 is the flash. Is it possible to save values on flash someplace at run-time?

I also have the possibility to use a SD card and the SDIO or SPI interface to store the values there, but if possible it would be best if a  SD card can be avoided.

The amount of data is only a few hundred bytes at most.

Comment: Yes, you can write to the flash, subject to the usual constraints of erase block size, limited rewrite life, and it being a relative slow and tricky operation.  ST has an app note describing how.  Additionally, some SWD-based flashing tools actually work by loading each block of data to RAM and then running a small program which stores that to flash.

Comment: A small serial EEPROM is sometimes a better solution. You can get SPI or I2C or Microwire versions, in SOIC-8 and even SOT-23 packages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what i know there are two options:

- Use flash (emulated as EEPROM for ease of use) according to this [Appnote](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00165693.pdf)
- Use the backup registers (20 byte of battery backed registers) according to the [Reference Manual](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00171190.pdf) Pages 67 And 79

By The Way if the you move one of the bigger brothers (F2-F4) of this chip you get a whole
part of ram battery backed something like 4k but it depends on the actual chip

Comment: The third option is to attach an external SPI (25xx), I2C (24xx), Microwire (93xx) or a 1-wire (11xx) serial EEPROM. http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/products/memory/serialEEPROM/home.html

Comment: Also the high density, e.g. STM32103VC has 84 byte of battery backed registers.